# Blazor server app can't use Chart JS zoom plugin

Tags: blazor, chart.js, blazor-server-side, chartjs-plugin-zoom

I tried to add to Blazor Server app graphs by using ChartJS. I used [tutorial](https://www.puresourcecode.com/dotnet/blazor/using-chart-js-with-blazor/#google_vignette) after some tweaks it started to work but no luck with plugin zoom.

I have used .Net 7.0, ChartJS 4.4.0 and zoom plugin 2.0.1.

I included js files in my project and added them to _Host.cshtml file:

```
    <script src="~/js/hammerjs.js"> </script>
    <script src="~/lib/Chart.js/dist/chart.umd.min.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/Chart.js/chart-plugin-zoom.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="~/js/chartInit.js"> </script>
```

so far i end up with config like that:

I have component for Chart:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div style="width:1000px; height:1000px;">
    <canvas id="@Id"></canvas>
</div>


@code {
    public enum ChartType
    {
        Pie,
        Bar,
        Line
    }

    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public ChartType Type { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public object[] Dataset { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        var config = new
        {
            type = Type.ToString().ToLower(),
            options = new
            {
                responsive = true,
                spanGaps = true,


            },
            scales = new
            {
                x = new
                {
                    type = "time"
                },
                y = new
                {
                    beginAtZero = true
                }
            },
            data = new
            {
                Datasets = Dataset,
                Labels = Labels
            },
            plugins = new
            {
                zoom = new
                {
                    pan = new
                    {
                        enabled = true,
                        mode = "x"
                    },
                    zoom = new
                    {
                        wheel = new
                        {
                            enabled = true
                        },
                        mode = "x",
                        drag = new
                        {
                            enabled = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", config);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setup", Id, config);
    }
}
```

Using this component:

```
<Chart Id="pie1" Type="@Chart.ChartType.Line"
       Dataset="@(new[] {
                            new JsChart_LineDataSet("1","blue",new List<float>(){4.0f, 6.0f, 9.0f, 12.0f,5f,9f}),
                            new JsChart_LineDataSet("2","green",new List<float>(){14.0f, 8.0f, 4.0f, 15.0f,11f,9f}),
                            new JsChart_LineDataSet("3","red",new List<float>(){12.0f, 3.0f, 7.0f, 35.0f,26f,22f}),
                            new JsChart_LineDataSet("4","orange",new List<float>(){1.0f, 12.0f, 3.0f, 6.0f,12f,24f})
                        }
               )"
       Labels="@(new[] { "0.1" , "0.2", "0.3", "0.4","0.5","0.6" })">
</Chart>
```

and the helper class:

```
    public class JsChart_LineDataSet
    {
        public string label { get; set; }
        public string backgroundColor { get; set; }
        public string borderColor { get; set; } 
        public List<float> data { get; set; }

        public JsChart_LineDataSet(string label, string backgroundColor, List<float> data)
        {
            this.label = label;
            this.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
            this.data = data;
            this.borderColor = backgroundColor;
        }
    }
```

result in browser:

[image]

I get no errors or warnings and panning or zooming don't work.

Have someone similar problem and have solution?